# Control Positioning of AdMob Banner in iOS via libGDX/RoboVM

Tags: ios, eclipse, libgdx, admob, robovm

I created my libGDX iOS project and I'm trying to position my AdMob ads to the bottom center of the screen but have no idea how to accomplish this. I'm using the bindings via RoboVM and do not know any of the RoboVM methods to control my ads. I copied the tutorial from [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx)  Does anyone have any tips or tutorials to help me accomplish this? Right now the ad seems to me missing 1/4 of whole banner ad is more towards the right of the screen. Below is my code:

```
public class IOSLauncher extends IOSApplication.Delegate implements IActivityRequestHandler{
private static final Logger log = new Logger(IOSLauncher.class.getName(), Application.LOG_DEBUG);
private static final boolean USE_TEST_DEVICES = true;
private GADBannerView adview;
private boolean adsInitialized = false;
private IOSApplication iosApplication;

@Override
protected IOSApplication createApplication() {
    IOSApplicationConfiguration config = new IOSApplicationConfiguration();
    config.orientationLandscape = true;
    config.orientationPortrait = false;

    iosApplication = new IOSApplication(new TestProject(this), config);
    return iosApplication;
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool();
    UIApplication.main(argv, null, IOSLauncher.class);
    pool.close();
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    initializeAds();

    final CGSize screenSize = UIScreen.getMainScreen().getBounds().size();
    double screenWidth = screenSize.width();

    final CGSize adSize = adview.getBounds().size();
    double adWidth = adSize.width();
    double adHeight = adSize.height();

    log.debug(String.format("Hidding ad. size[%s, %s]", adWidth, adHeight));

    float bannerWidth = (float) screenWidth;
    float bannerHeight = (float) (bannerWidth / adWidth * adHeight);

    adview.setFrame(new CGRect(0, -bannerHeight, bannerWidth, bannerHeight));
}

@Override
public void show() {
    initializeAds();

    final CGSize screenSize = UIScreen.getMainScreen().getBounds().size();
    double screenWidth = screenSize.width();

    final CGSize adSize = adview.getBounds().size();
    double adWidth = adSize.width();
    double adHeight = adSize.height();

    log.debug(String.format("Showing ad. size[%s, %s]", adWidth, adHeight));

    float bannerWidth = (float) screenWidth;
    float bannerHeight = (float) (bannerWidth / adWidth * adHeight);

    adview.setFrame(new CGRect((screenWidth / 2) - adWidth / 2, 0, bannerWidth, bannerHeight));
}

public void initializeAds() {
    if (!adsInitialized) {
        log.debug("Initalizing ads...");

        adsInitialized = true;

        adview = new GADBannerView(GADAdSize.banner());
        adview.setAdUnitID(Constants.AdUnitID); //put your secret key here
        adview.setRootViewController(iosApplication.getUIViewController());


        iosApplication.getUIViewController().getView().addSubview(adview);

        final GADRequest request = GADRequest.create();

        adview.setDelegate(new GADBannerViewDelegateAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void didReceiveAd(GADBannerView view) {
                super.didReceiveAd(view);
                log.debug("didReceiveAd");
            }

            @Override
            public void didFailToReceiveAd(GADBannerView view,
                    GADRequestError error) {
                super.didFailToReceiveAd(view, error);
                log.debug("didFailToReceiveAd:" + error);
            }
        });

        adview.loadRequest(request);

        log.debug("Initalizing ads complete.");
    }
}

@Override
public void showAds(boolean show) {
    initializeAds();

    final CGSize screenSize = UIScreen.getMainScreen().getBounds().size();
    double screenWidth = screenSize.width();

    final CGSize adSize = adview.getBounds().size();
    double adWidth = adSize.width();
    double adHeight = adSize.height();

    log.debug(String.format("Hidding ad. size[%s, %s]", adWidth, adHeight));

    float bannerWidth = (float) screenWidth;
    float bannerHeight = (float) (bannerWidth / adWidth * adHeight);

    if(show) {
        adview.setFrame(new CGRect((screenWidth / 2) - adWidth / 2, 0, bannerWidth, bannerHeight));
    } else {
        adview.setFrame(new CGRect(0, -bannerHeight, bannerWidth, bannerHeight));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set the ad position with

```
adview.setFrame(CGRect);
```

if you inspect the parameters of **CGRect** it's like;

```
CGRect(double x, double y, double width, double height)
```

0,0 coordinates (x,y) is top left. so, your code;

```
// center of screen
double adX = (screenWidth / 2) - (adWidth / 2);
// bottom of screen
double adY = screenHeight - bannerHeight;

adview.setFrame(new CGRect(adX, adY, bannerWidth, bannerHeight));
```

and the other important thing, you should not manipulate the positioning in two method! your **showAds** method should be like;

```
public void showAds(boolean show) {
    if (show) {
        show();
    } else {
        hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... that works great, but now my hide method isn't working. Do you have a working show() method that works?

Comment: Nevermind... I got it, I just did this and it works... 

adview.setFrame(new CGRect(0, -adHeight, adWidth, adHeight));